# Pandas df.mode ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe (named all_samples_z_df) with some null values:

```
        sample1     sample2    sample3  mean median mode
pos1      2           4           2       2     2
pos2      1                       1       1     1   
pos3      3           5                   4     4
```

When I create mean or median columns there is no problem, but when I try to create mode column I get this error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 5, placement implies 1

I was using this commands, which are indicated in pandas manuals, but I get the error for the mode. Do you know how can I solve this?

```
all_samples_z_df['mean'] = all_samples_z_df.mean(axis=1)
all_samples_z_df['median'] = all_samples_z_df.median(axis=1)
all_samples_z_df['mode'] = all_samples_z_df.mode(axis=1)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Comment: `all_samples_z_df['mode'] = all_samples_z_df.mode(axis=1).iloc[:,0]` ? : mode returns a df per docs , hence take the first column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that "empty" fields in your DataFrame are printed as **spaces**
(instead of *NaN*).
So I assume that each of your columns containg at least one space is
of **object** type.
To verify it run `all_samples_z_df.info()`.

To count *mean* and *median*, all *sample...* columns should be of
**numeric** type, otherwise they are ignored.

This "ignore case" is visible from the result of *mean* column.
Note that the actual mean value for the first row is:

```
(2 + 4 + 2) / 3 = 2.666667
```

But your mean for row 1 is just **2**, so apparently only *sample1* column
has been counted.

To have proper types of value, in my test I created a source file containig:

```
,sample1,sample2,sample3
pos1,2,4,2
pos2,1,,1
pos3,3,5,
```

and read it calling:

```
all_samples_z_df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', index_col=0)
```

getting:

```
      sample1  sample2  sample3
pos1        2      4.0      2.0
pos2        1      NaN      1.0
pos3        3      5.0      NaN
```

so now "empty" values are printed as *NaN*.

When you run `all_samples_z_df.info()`, you will see that

- *sample1* column is of *int64* type,
- both remaining columns are of *float64* type.

Another hint: When you compute all your functions, you should take 3 initial
columns **only**.
Otherwise columns computed earlier are included as source in other calculations,
what is probably not what you want.

Now, without any obstacles, you can run:

```
all_samples_z_df['mean'] = all_samples_z_df.iloc[:, 0:3].mean(axis=1)
all_samples_z_df['median'] = all_samples_z_df.iloc[:, 0:3].median(axis=1)
```

(note `iloc[:, 0:3].` added to both instructions).

So far the result is:

```
      sample1  sample2  sample3      mean  median
pos1        2      4.0      2.0  2.666667     2.0
pos2        1      NaN      1.0  1.000000     1.0
pos3        3      5.0      NaN  4.000000     4.0
```

And now run `all_samples_z_df.iloc[:, 0:3].mode(axis=1)` (just to see the result):

```
        0    1
pos1  2.0  NaN
pos2  1.0  NaN
pos3  3.0  5.0
```

meaning that:

- for 2 first rows the most often occurring value is *2* and *1*, respectively.
- but in the third row there are **two** values occurring most often (equal
  number of occurrences):

  - the first is *3*,
  - and the second is *5*.

And just this is the source of your problem: **Two** items (3 and 5) have been
passed as the content of the new column in the last row.

One of possible solutions is to use only the first from many values, so you can run:

```
all_samples_z_df['mode'] = all_samples_z_df.iloc[:, 0:3].mode(axis=1)[0]
```

instead (note added *[0]*).

The result is now:

```
      sample1  sample2  sample3      mean  median  mode
pos1        2      4.0      2.0  2.666667     2.0   2.0
pos2        1      NaN      1.0  1.000000     1.0   1.0
pos3        3      5.0      NaN  4.000000     4.0   3.0
```